# Why is sys_call_table predictable?

Tags: kernel, kernel-modules, syscalls

In (or after?) 2.4 the `sys_call_table` symbol was no longer exported to make it harder to hook system calls.

Ignoring that you can still obtain this information from the IDT or by reading `/boot/System.map-<kernel-version>`, I was wondering why this address seems to be constant across reboots and machines (with the same kernel version)? Is it just not worth making it dynamic? Is there a reason requiring it to be static?

What I am aiming at is this:

`sys_call_table` is no longer exported to modules in order to make hooking syscalls a little harder, but modules (i.e. kernel-space programs) can still easily get this info from reading `System.map` or simply guessing based on the kernel release information as the address seems to be identical for all machines running the same version of the kernel.

Comment: Have you tried looking for the syscall table in memory? Unless you’re booting with `nokaslr`, on kernels since 4.8, the syscall table isn’t at the address given by `System.map`...

Comment: interesting, so far all 3.x kernels from Ubuntu and Debian have had the System.map accurate, but now with a 4.x kernel I observe that mismatch, too. Thanks! Does that mean it changes between boots or different hosts?

Comment: It changes at every boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since at least version 4.8 of the kernel, at least on x86, the kernel address space is randomised, including the system call table’s address. See [`RANDOMIZE_BASE` in the kernel configuration](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/x86/Kconfig#n2079) for the basic details.

This means that the address given in `System.map` is useless, and the address of the system call table changes at every boot. If you need to debug something and want to use `System.map`, you need to boot with the `nokaslr` kernel command-line parameter to disable KASLR.

Comment: Thanks! Great to see that 4.8 and upwards do this :) It should be noted that, if enabled, `/proc/kallsyms` might contain this address but it does indeed change with every boot.

Comment: In any case IDT doesn't point to syscall, and it is in lower memory. Intel processors doesn't allow to call or jump to kernel (from outside) (but with call gates, traps gates, exceptions, and interrupt gates). And in call gates, the effective address is unused. So the problem is different than normal ASLR. On Kernel: side channels, see Meldtown, but such bug showed that kernel address was still leaked.